# JSplitPane slide only to one side

Tags: java, swing, jtree, jeditorpane, jsplitpane

Im not sure why, but the slider only goes to the left and even locks the new position.
It uses a modificated version of the NestedJSplitPane tutorial with JTree and JEditorPane.
My guess is, that the JEditorPane causes the problem...

```
public frameMenu(){
    JEditorPane htmlPane;
    JTree parkSelect;
    JTree triggerSelect;
    URL helpURL;

    DefaultMutableTreeNode left = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Tree Left");
    DefaultMutableTreeNode triggerTree = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Tree Down");
    //nNode.createNodes();

    int HORIZSPLIT = JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT;
    int VERTSPLIT = JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT;

    boolean continuousLayout = true;

    parkSelect = new JTree(left);
    parkSelect.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);

    htmlPane = new JEditorPane();
    htmlPane.setEditable(true);

    triggerSelect = new JTree(triggerTree);
    triggerSelect.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);

    JSplitPane splitPane1 = new JSplitPane(VERTSPLIT, continuousLayout, htmlPane, triggerSelect);
    splitPane1.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
    splitPane1.setDividerSize(2);
    splitPane1.setDividerLocation(0.5);

    JSplitPane splitPane2 = new JSplitPane(HORIZSPLIT, parkSelect, splitPane1);
    splitPane2.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
    splitPane2.setDividerLocation(0.4);
    splitPane2.setDividerSize(2);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Trigger Editor");
    frame.setSize(600, 400);
    frame.add(splitPane2);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

This is more of an snipped, but the problem is the same.
Im not sure, how much code i could put in one post.

The up and down split can be slided without problems, but left and right causes problems.

Comment: setDividerLocatin(double) is pointless when the component isn't displayed on a realised component, as 0.5 / 0 isn't much at all

Comment: good idea, but that wasnt my problem. The slider only goes to one side and sticks there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the slider only goes to the left and even locks the new position

A `JSplitPane` respects the minimums size of a component.

> My guess is, that the JEditorPane causes the problem...

Correct, the minimum size of the JEditorPane appears to be equal to its preferred size.

You will need to override the `getMinimumSize()` method of you `JEditorPane` to return a more reasonable value for your requirments:

```
htmlPane = new JEditorPane()
{
    @Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize()
    {
        Dimension d = super.getMinimumSize();
        d.width = 100;

        return d;
    }
};
```

Comment: Awesome! Took me some time to figure out, that i had to replace `htmlPane = new JEditorPane();` with your override. Thank you.